# Inaccessible JavaScript object property

Tags: javascript, console

Strange problem.

I'm investigating an object in the console. One of the properties is not accessible through JavaScript, but it is accessible through the console.

Is it possible to access the property through JavaScript?

This is the output from console.log(marker,marker.ie,marker.map):

[image: console.log(marker,marker.ie,marker.map)]

Here's the marker.ie property opened up in the console:

[image: marker.ie property opened up in console]

Comment: The console log in google chrome looks at the object when you expand it, not when you log it. So the state you see in console is recorded at the time you view it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that, at the time of the `console.log` that the value of `marker.ie` is `undefined`. It might be getting defined later, this explains why it will show if you print the whole of `marker`.

Maybe you should wait on some event to complete?

Comment: That was it... thanks! Until now, I thought that console.log captured an object at a moment in time.

Comment: I think it does for literal objects (`{}`), but not for class instances (`new`). This may change over time so take the validity of this statement with a grain of salt.